# In which way do kinds associate in haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, data-kinds, type-kinds

i have given the task to give an example for a type constructor of the kind

`* -> (* -> *)`

but I can't find one.

My guess is that kinds associate to the right, so that the above given kind is the same as

`* -> * -> *`

In that case `Either` would be an example, wouldn't it?

Comment: Just remember that `(Type -> Type) -> Type` is not the same, which is the kind of `newtype Fix f = In (f (Fix f)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

```
Prelude> :set -XKindSignatures 
Prelude> :k (Either :: * -> (* -> *))
(Either :: * -> (* -> *)) :: * -> * -> *
```

BTW, the `*` notation will be deprecated. The modern version is called [`Type`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Kind.html#t:Type).

```
Either :: Type -> Type -> Type
```

Comment: (Which you may have to import from GHC.Types)

Comment: Importing from [`Data.Kind`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Kind.html) is recommended